# How many wash cycles should I aim for when washing brown rice?

Tags: rice, cleaning, rice-cooker

I was told that I'm supposed to keep washing the brown rice with water, empty the pot out, and repeat until the water doesn't become foggy anymore to get rid of the arsenic.  For each cycle, I pat, squeeze, and swirl the rice around for roughly 1 minute. I've done this 12 cycles now and the water still remains foggy. Should I keep going or is that enough?

Comment: I do 3 rinses, and the 3rd rinse is always clear. Do you swirl the grains around by hand or with a spoon during each rinse? It sound like something is wrong with your technique.

Comment: I use my hands @WayfaringStranger

Comment: Often the reason for washing the excess starch out of white long-grain rice is to achieve perfectly separated grains at the end of cooking. This isn't so much of a problem with brown rice. I would wash it enough to make sure it's clean: no more.

Answer (score 3):

The cloudiness you see in your rinse water is starch, not arsenic.

The amount of arsenic still present after rinsing off the starch and cooking the rice is safe according to the FDA.
https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/arsenic-in-rice_us_589cc1ffe4b09bd304c0b04c